# Google Earth Engine: Rename Assets

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a simple question: how do you rename your Assets in Google Earth Engine (I'm not talking about the files within the Assets)? For some reason I cannot rename it and I have a hard time creating a new one and delete the older folder!

Comment: For example, currently my assets is named: users/2019_NB and I want to change it to 2020_NB, how can I do that? Was this example helpful? Thank you for your response btw, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An asset ID looks like this:

```
users/username/some/path/name
```

It's easy to rename an asset or an intermediate folder (some, path, or name). Just click on the pencil icon when hovering over the asset/folder in the code editor. What you're asking for is changing the username. That you cannot do yourself. You'll have to talk to Google about that.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really helpful!

Comment: Note: At this time, the Earth Engine team can not support requests to change username.